# OncePerRequestFilter and filter invocation

Tags: java, spring

I am learning spring security and I came across the concept of filters. On reading a little bit what I understood is that dispatcher servlet receives the request first (also called the front controller for the same reason), after that it calls a certain mapper which helps to invoke the required controller method. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong somewhere.

Further I came across OncePerRequestFilter, I referred this link to understand it :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-onceperrequestfilter

In an example mentioned here :

```
@Controller
public class HelloController  {
    @GetMapping(path = "/greeting")
    public DeferredResult<String> hello(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        executorService.submit(() -> perform(deferredResult));
        return deferredResult;
    }
    private void perform(DeferredResult<String> dr) {
        // some processing 
        dr.setResult("OK");
    }
}
```

it says that if we use a normal Filter, it will be invoked twice,
1- because of the TOMCAT/http-worker thread and
2- because of the new thread branched out

My doubt is that how come branching out a new thread invokes the filter again. I mean my understanding was that filter just sits between dispatcher servlet and controller. After it has reached controller there is no filter coming in between, during the controller method processing.

Can anyone please help me understand the same.

In a nutshell, I have 2 doubts :

1- how spanning a new thread in controller may invoke the filter again, in case of async/defferedresult
2- does it means that for synchronous requests we dont need OncePerRequestFilter explicitly, It'll be anyway only once. If not, then in what case will the filter be invoked twice in case of Sync requests.

Comment: Because that is how async request processing works according to the servlet api specification. When processing/generating the actual response, it might be that the filter does some setup of attributes etc. etc. and that needs to be done again.

Comment: so for sync requests, we may not need OncePerRequestFilter ?

Comment: Yes you do as you don't want to execute the filter again on a forward for instance.

Comment: but once the filter is executed, why would it be invoked again ?

Comment: A forward is a new entry in the chain and will invoke the filters again, I suggest you read up on how forwards/redirects work.

Comment: sure, I am not aware of this concept. Do you have link to any resources ?

Comment: The Servlet API.